# how to deploy Laravel 5 app on ubuntu pc for production?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, php

i want to deploy a laravel 5 app on my ubuntu pc having php,mysql,apache,composer installed.

one way is to use

**`php artisan serve`**

**but i think it's not the best way to do that** because it can only handle 1 or 2 request at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deploy your Larave 5 application on Ubuntu. you can use php,apache composer also.

PHP artisan serve is used for running development server. The purpose is to check if all functionality is working fine or not. It is not recommended to use this at deployment.

you have to follow the commands specified below.
1. Install apache server.
2. Install PHP and other extensions (php-mysql, php-mcrypt,php-mbstring) which are must for Laravel.
3. change the permissions for your laravel project.
for ex.

```
chown -R apache.apache /var/www/laravel
chmod -R 755 /var/www/laravel
chmod -R 777 /var/www/laravel/app/storage
```

4. Create virtual host.

ServerName laravel.example.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/laravel/public
   
      AllowOverride All

5.Restart Server and check url.